# Javascript and ctrl key conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

There is `div` where I am using `onclick` function to redirect on some other page.

But when I am using ctrl key and mouse, the link is opening in next tab as well as in same tab. Ideally, it should open in new tab only.

Code is as follows:

```
<div onclick="window.location='some page url'">
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with onclck? That's default browser behavior anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, you are right. But when I am using simple `window.location="some url"` same thing happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this :

```
<a href="some page url">
 <div></div>
</a>
```

So, when you click it's open in the same tab and when you press ctrl key, it's opening in a new tab.

**EDIT :** So now try this :

```
<div onclick="doRedirect()"></div>

<script>
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.which=="17")
            cntrlIsPressed = true;
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(){
        cntrlIsPressed = false;
    });

    var cntrlIsPressed = false;


    function doRedirect()
    {
        if(cntrlIsPressed)
        { 
           window.open('some url','_blank');
        }
        else{
           window.location('some url');
        } 

    }
</script>
```

You can also specify the url in parameters.

Comment: I know this. But I cannot do this. Its not my requirement.

Comment: So what's your requirement ?

Comment: I want to redirect when click on `div` only. I cannot use `<a href="">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="window.open(
  'https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);">
Click to open in tab
</div>
```

here is the working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zm07pcwL/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is preventing default function of click. When clicking on it with mouse, it should redirect on page in same tab. And when pressing mouse with ctrl key, it should open only in new tab.